# Transform path with ".." elements to absolute path, in a script?

Tags: bash, shell, path, sh, relative-path

So when coding a bash/sh script I got a path in a variable with the following content:

```
$SOMEPATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/../..
```

How can I convert $SOMEVAR to a full absolute path that converts the ".." folders to this value?:

```
$SOMEFULLPATH=/usr
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `readlink`:

```
readlink -f "$SOMEPATH"
```

```
   -f, --canonicalize
          canonicalize  by  following  every symlink in every component of
          the given name recursively; all  but  the  last  component  must
          exist

   -m, --canonicalize-missing
          canonicalize by following every symlink in  every  component  of
          the  given  name recursively, without requirements on components
          existence
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from @devnull I would recommend `readlink`, however the `-m` option does not require any part of the file path to already exist, which is more flexible.
`readlink -m $SOMEFULLPATH`